# Windows Administrator Access Logs

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, windows-domain

I recently learnt that domain administrators can remotely access files and directories for any computer that is a member of that domain. For example, an Administrator can access the root folder of a PC that has an IP address 192.168.29.xx, by browsing `\\192.168.29.xx\C$` from the file explorer.

How do I get to know whether my Domain Administrator was able to access the files in my PC??

Comment: You want to see an audit of if/when someone was looking at files on your machine?

Comment: Check if the following article can help you:https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-changes-made-to-files-of-shared-folder.html

Comment: Yes @spikey_richie, that is exactly what I want to see

Comment: Thanks @Candy, the article only explains for shared folders. I've followed the steps in vain.